How can I fix this plumbing where the PVC from the sink doesn't line up with the rough in?
Full disclosure. Years ago I replaced a double sided sink to a single sink with the drain in the middle. The drain didn't quite like up with the rough-in and I didn't feel comfortable doing a bunch of cutting with the PVC so I rigged it to look like this. I'd really like to improve on this, but I don't want to get a bunch of PVC, make a bunch of mistakes, and be underneath my sink for the next eight hours. Could someone give me an idea to improve on this?
For the record I'm embarrassed to show this, but it has worked for me with no leaks. The sink drains slower than I'd like. I have an idea on how to improve this, but it's probably a bad idea and I think it's best I ask more experienced people.


Can the pipe going to the floor turn?

As a fix-it type person, I am always frustrated that PVC is permanent after you glue it. Copper or galvanized have their downsides, but at least you can take them apart and re-do them.

A design would be much easier if you had a horizontal drain instead of vertical. Because you have a vertical drain out the base of your cabinet the challenge in redesigning your undersink plumbing is doing it in a way that avoids building an S trap. An S trap is prohibited by code because the suction of water draining out of the trap may empty the weir allowing sewer gas to vent into the house.

In order to solve this, the horizontal PVC extension out  of your P trap must be at least twice the diameter of the pipe and be vented. If you can't tap into an existing vent you might be able to vent with an AAV (Air Admittance Valve). The AAV allows air into the drain and prevents suction that would drain the water seal in the P trap. Below is a rough diagram of what this may look like.

The device at the top right of the illustration is the AAV.

The key here is to cut the vertical PVC drain pipe (the one going out the bottom of the cabinet) and put on a new 90° elbow at a height and angle that you can hit easily with the tailpiece(s) and trap from the sink.
Pick up some pre-made tailpieces, a new trap, PVC elbow and waste fittings to see what you can fit together. Grab everything at the store that might be useful to experiment with — they are cheap, compared to another trip to the store, so it's not a big deal if you have some left over. Working with new, clean parts is also nicer. Do your test fitting before cutting or gluing anything if you can. While you are fitting it together, keep in mind that you can cut pre-made parts like the tailpiece(s)* if you need to.
Your goal at this point will be to get the outlet of the trap and the elbow + waste fitting on the PVC at the same height and relative angle. It is hard to say from the picture, but it seems likely you can arrange things so that the horizontal outlet from the trap goes directly into an elbow + waste fitting glued on the vertical pipe.

Depending on how everything goes, you may need to cut the PVC before you can finalize things. (I used to be the kind of guy that tried to figure everything out ahead of time and buy only, exactly what I needed... now I have a box of extra drain parts and PVC fittings.)
Personally, I would try to angle that towards the back so that the trap loops behind the tailpiece from the sink to leave a bit more usable space. You may find the outlet will only line up if it is wrapped the other way, though.
The outlet of the trap may end up too high after cutting and replacing the elbow on the vertical PVC. You have three ways to adjust the height where they come together  • Extend or cut the tailpiece coming down from the sink,• use a long-turn elbow on the PVC drain pipe, • cut or add a coupling + extension to the vertical PVC drain pipe.

Those flexible adapters are something I avoid (the ones like bendy straws) because they collect crud over time. If you are reluctant to cut the permanent PVC drain pipe, just plan ahead carefully and only cut after you know how everything will go together.
